# How to integrate the Paypal Account Live

Tags: angular6

We aren't able to process your payment using your PayPal account at this time. Please go back to the merchant and try using a different payment method
how to make the paypal account live using angular6 i have tried with this code but its not working,its working fine with sandbox but with its not working with production level

```
**code**

import { Component,AfterViewChecked  } from '@angular/core';
declare let paypal: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
  addScript: boolean = false;
  paypalLoad: boolean = true;

  finalAmount: number = 1;

  paypalConfig = {
    env: 'production',
    client: {
     //sandbox: '';
      production:'';
    },
    commit: true,
    payment: (data, actions) => {
      return actions.payment.create({
        payment: {
          transactions: [
            { amount: { total: this.finalAmount, currency: 'USD' } }
          ]
        }
      });
    },
    onAuthorize: (data, actions) => {
      return actions.payment.execute().then((payment) => {
        alert('Transaction completed');
        //Do something when payment is successful.
      })
    }
  };

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    if (!this.addScript) {
      this.addPaypalScript().then(() => {
        paypal.Button.render(this.paypalConfig, '#paypal-checkout-btn');
        this.paypalLoad = false;
      })
    }
  }

  addPaypalScript() {
    this.addScript = true;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let scripttagElement = document.createElement('script');    
      scripttagElement.src = 'https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js';
      scripttagElement.onload = resolve;
      document.body.appendChild(scripttagElement);
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Things should work fine when you switch from sandbox to production mode - make sure you passing proper credentials. 
The mentioned error may occur for various reasons more details would be needed to look into the issue, hence suggest you to raise a query ticket at PayPal Support team https://www.paypal-support.com/s/?language=en_US